# mongo command line vs shell: different results

Tags: mongodb, shell

I'm puzzled by a problem I'm having with the Mongo Shell producing different variations on the output.

When I log into the mongo shell and run the simplest of queries, such as:

```
db.database.findOne();
```

I get a document returned.

When I invoke the same command through the --eval option on the command line, I get a different result: (xx's redact sensitive info)

```
mongo -u xxx -p xxx xxxx --eval 'db.database.findOne();'
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: xxxx
[object Object]
```

And when I put this command in a file and try it, I get no output at all.

```
mongo -u xxx-p xxx xxxx example.js
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: xxxx
```

(I just get returned to a command line here)

Example.js contains:

```
db.database.findOne();
```

What part of the Mongo shell manual did I miss that explains this behavior?

My goal is to be able to feed the output of my mongo query into a shell script.

Comment: Wrap your eval with a printjson() and give http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo a read ( 'printjson(db.database.findOne());')

Comment: This was the answer, and a very helpful one.  Thank you James!   Can you enter it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one and recognize your contribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `findOne()` is run within the shell it will print the result in JSON as a convenience. To print the same via shell script or eval you need to print the return value via a `printjson()` call:

```
mongo -u xxx -p xxx xxxx --eval 'printjson(db.database.findOne());'
```

For more on scripting with the `mongo` shell see the [official MongoDB Shell docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell).